# Using Indy10 components to download from alphavantage.co

Tags: c++builder, indy10

I am working with financial data downloads from https://www.alphavantage.co. I am trying to get the download working in C++Builder XE4 Pro

To access the data you need a free ApiKey here https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key

The request below works using a web browser. It saves a .csv file.

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=KEYHERE&datatype=csv

In C++BuilderXE4 I am using the VCL 32 bit platform and three Indy components version 10.6.0.497.

IdHTTP

IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL

IdCookieManager

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
UnicodeString f;

IdHTTP1->IOHandler = IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
IdHTTP1->CookieManager = IdCookieManager1;

TMemoryStream *s = new TMemoryStream;
s->Position = 0;

f = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=KEYHERE&datatype=csv";

IdHTTP1->Get(f.c_str(), s);

Memo1->Lines->LoadFromStream(s);
}
```

When I run this code I am getting the error below.

Error Connecting with SSL
error:14094438:SSL routines::SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error

I believe this error means the server is rejecting my request. My question is this: Is it possible to make this request with Indy components(or any other components) or do I have to write some custom code using a library like libcurl?

Comment: The server is not rejecting your HTTP request. It is rejecting your SSL/TLS connection, before the HTTP request can even be sent. Your SSLIOHandler is not configured in a way that works for this server. For instance, the most likely culprit is a mismatched `SSLVersions` property. Indy enables only TLS v1.0 by default, but many sites are disabling TLS v1.0 and now require TLS v1.1+. Try enabling TLS v1.1 and v1.2 in the `SSLVersions` property and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: On a side note, there is no need to call `c_str()` since `Get()` takes a `UnicodeString` as input. And you need to seek the stream's `Position` back to 0 before calling `LoadFromStream()`, otherwise it won't load anything. Though technically you don't even need the stream at all, you can do this instead: `Memo1->Text = IdHTTP1->Get(f);`

Comment: I tried every combination of SSLVersions in the Indy component but could not get it too download. I was able to get the download to work with the component CppWebBrowser and the TMS Software component named TWebCopy. I prefer to use Indy components but in this case I will use one of these other two components. Thanks.

Comment: I said that was just a *possibility*. There could be other factors at play. You are going to have to sniff the TCP traffic with a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to see what is different between Indy's SSL/TLS handshake and a web browser's SSL/TLS handshake.